Can consciousness perceive time, and if so, how?
Consciousness can perceive qualia, such as the "redness of red." But is there a specific quale for time? One might argue that we know time is real because we are conscious of our memories of the past. While I’m happy to grant that consciousness can access memories, those memories are arguably experienced now, in the present moment. However, being conscious of memories doesn’t seem equivalent to being conscious of time itself. In fact, one might entertain hypotheses such as time being an illusion, with all your memories merely implanted.
And yet, we have a strong intuition that time is real and that we are aware of its passage.
Can consciousness perceive time, and if so, how?

NOTE: Answers that simply claim, "we can trivially know that time exists by being conscious of our memories of the past," would need to explain how we can rule out the possibility that those memories were not truly caused by a real past but are instead brute facts of a solipsistic world or something similar.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I highly recommend this article from SEP and its supplement that discusses temporal consciousness specifically.
One model in particular of "time consciousness" that I find compelling states that time is intrinsic to experience. You cannot have an experience of zero duration, there is always some nominal duration to any moment of consciousness, however brief (even a femtosecond is infinitely longer than an instant).

Extensional Model: our episodes of experiencing are themselves temporally extended, and are thus able to incorporate change and persistence in a quite straightforward way. Our streams of consciousness are composed of successions of these extended phases of experience.

The concept dates back to William James at least and is referred to as the specious present -- that what we call "now" is "temporally thick" as opposed to being identical to any particular instant t0 of physical time.

In his influential writings on these matters William James argued that to make sense of our temporal experience we need to distinguish the strict or mathematical present from the experiential or specious present: whereas the first is indeed durationless, the second is experienced as possessing a brief duration, sufficient to accommodate the change and persistence we find in our immediate experience. Proponents of the cinematic model maintain that James was mistaken: to make sense of our temporal experience we don’t need anything resembling an extended specious present. Proponents of the extensional and retentional views maintain that we do need something resembling a specious present, but offer very different accounts of it.1


The above is a possible model of "phenomenal time" -- but we still need to determine the metaphysical nature of time -

"block/eternal" universe: All history already exists, but no global "now"
"spotlight": All history exists, but global "now"
"growing block": global past exists, open future created by global "now"
"presentist": only now exists

2-4 best match our immediate experiences and intuition, but 1 is the picture we get from our most well supported models of physics. The question is how do we make sense of "now" in an eternalist block universe (or passage of time at all).

+1 Thanks for the James reference - I didn't know the term "specious present". It seems my own answer is very much aligned with this :)

Time is not directly experienced. We don't see or perceive time as such, but we see change and movement around us. Insofar as we observe the same thing moving or changing, we are indirectly aware of time. In Kantian terms, time is not a perceived piece of data, but is the form or structure in which we perceive things. So, in a way, consciousness is time.
There are no "point" experiences. Any experience will have a start, middle, and end; it will have a duration, even if we cannot unambiguously split it up into 'start', 'middle', 'end'. It's integrated in memories and expectations. Trying to strip off the memories and expectations will empty the experience of any actual content or meaning (and definitely of any subjective, experienced meaning). The flow of consciousness doesn't break up into discrete points -- at least not in how it appears to us. Certain experiences may appear to be "closer" to a "pure" experience of time -- for instance, waiting, boredom, eager anticipation, nostalgia, a growing hunger. But still, time is not directly experienced in those. It's the form that gives the experience its (temporal) structure.
Memories are integrated in our perceptions. It's impossible to perceive anything specific, and it's impossible to have any determinate feelings or apperceptions, without having memories.
How do I know my memories are not false memories? Because my memories are not just an "internal", "private" collection of postcards that I can inspect at leisure. Other people also know about them. My memories are not just a random collection of facts, either. But in some cases, in principle, I may not know if a particular memory is a false memory or not. There are even ways to almost deliberately, knowingly generate false memories. (Maya Bar-Hillel gives an amusing account of this in The unbearable lightness of self-induced mind-corruption.) But, up to some extent, all our memories may be false. If Pentti Kanerva's model of distributed associative memory is also applicable to human memory, then any act of retrieval (of a memory trace) may change how that memory is stored and thereby slightly alter the memory. Whether that amounts to really falsifying the memory depends on how strict we want to be.
When someone shows you an old photograph of a toddler and tells you "That's you when you were a toddler!", how then do you know if the photograph is really one of you? Based on the photograph alone there may be no way of telling. But in general, there are ways to convince someone. There needs to be a sequence of events between a moment in the past, when that picture was taken, and the current moment, when you're presented with it -- a sequence of events that links up those moments in a plausible (causal) story. And actually, since you may not have a memory of the picture being taken, you may just have to believe your parents, who tell you that that was you. But there may be enough circumstantial evidence to justify this belief (for instance, lots of other photos). In being told these kind of things, by people who we can only trust, we learn language (the meaning of "that" and "you") and we learn to recognize ourselves.

When thinking about time, I cannot help but recall Tao Yuanming's poems. They come closest, in my opinion, to expressing an experience of time, and show at the same time, how paradoxical this 'experience' is. The following poem is one of his most famous, it's the first one in a sequence called 時運 (The Turn of the Season). (Note that Chinese uses the same word for "season" and "time").

邁邁時運，穆穆良朝。
襲我春服，薄言東郊。
山滌余靄，宇曖微霄。
有風自南，翼彼新苗。
Swiftly the years, beyond recall.
Solemn the stillness of this fair morning.
I will clothe myself in spring-clothing
And visit the slopes of the Eastern Hill.
By the mountain-stream a mist hovers,
Hovers a moment, then scatters.
There comes a wind blowing from the south
That brushes the fields of new corn.
(tr. Arthur Waley, A Hundred and Seventy Chinese Poems)

William Empson, in Seven Types of Ambiguity (1930) analyses the ambiguities in the first two lines:

The human mind has two main scales on which to measure time. The large one takes the length of a human life as its unit, so that
there is nothing to be done about life, it is of an animal dignity
and simplicity, and must be regarded from a peaceable and fatalistic point of view. The small one takes as its unit the conscious moment, and it is from this that you consider the neighbouring space, an activity of the will, delicacies of social tone, and your personality. (...)
Both these time-scales and their contrasts are included by these
two lines in a single act of apprehension, because of the words
swift and still. Being contradictory as they stand, they demand
to be conceived in different ways. (...)
[But] these scales, being both present are in some degree used for
each adjective, so that the words are ambiguous in a more direct sense; the years of a man's life seem swift even on the small scale, like the mist from the mountains which 'gathers a moment, then scatters'; the morning seems still even on the large scale, so that this moment is apocalyptic and a type of heaven.

The poem is an old man's poem, but the Chinese text almost reads like a children's poem (a poem written by a child, for children). The language both echoes the Shi Jing, the old Book of Songs, in the alliterations of the first two lines, and is deceptively like plain-old farmer's speech. I believe almost everyone can recognize the expressed awareness and feelings.

There are two answers to this question, depending on whether you accept the "objection" in the question as a given or not.
If you accept the objection that:

memories are arguably experienced now, in the present moment. However, being conscious of memories doesn’t seem equivalent to being conscious of time itself. In fact, one might entertain hypotheses such as time being an illusion, with all your memories merely implanted.

then all you can experience is the now, and therefore no, you cannot experience "time itself" (if to experience "time itself" is to experience the passage of time). The objection undercuts any conception of time perception that relies on memory of past events (e.g. "What is the Perception of Time?")
Of course, if you consider experiencing a particular moment in time an experience of "time itself," the answer becomes "yes." One may not realize one is experiencing time in that case, but this would admittedly be a narrow view of what it means to experience time. This is the concept of experiencing the present as present (see Section 5, "Past, present and the passage of time")."
However, if instead, you do not take that objection as a given, and you accept that you have memories of the past, even moments barely past, that are roughly accurate, and that can reveal changes that have happened in the world, then you can experience time through accessing and experiencing those memories.
If you further want to know how to decide between these two worlds, that is a question about solipsism or the like, which already has been asked about in many other Q&As on this site.

Experiment: silently hum a tune to yourself -- try not to even subvocalize it. Use a stopwatch to measure how long it takes you to get through the song. Notice that you are doing so in tempo, and in a tempo that matches duration in the outside world.
Clearly there is something in your internal awareness that is tracking time. Whether it is entirely in the consciousness, or in peripheral awareness of body processes that provide time references, would be damned hard to test, and frankly I'm not sure that distinction is a useful one.
It isn't clear what you perceive time as, other than duration. Or if that question has any meaning.
